# primeng p table not sorting and column select not toggling

Tags: angular, primeng

I try to implement primeNg p-table. The data are passed to child component:
My response object is an input and i do have something like this:

```
...
"DOCUMENTS":[
  {
     "SystemFields":{
        "Category":"Cat1",
        "Date":"2020-09-14 11:20:15",
        "DocId":"29-515-1",
        "Type":"pdf"
     },
     "Indexes":{
        "idx1":"val1",
        "idx2":"2019-08-23",
        "idx3":2745.6,
        "idx4":"val2",
        "idx4":"val3"
     }
  }, ...
]
```

I get access to the documents in ngOnChanges. here is my component:

```
export class ResultTableComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input() response: DocumentsResponseModel;
  documents: Document[];
  dataset: any[];
  cols: Cols[] = [];
  @ViewChild('dt') dt: Table;
  _selectedColumns: any[];

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    this.cols = [];
    let documents = this.response.DOCUMENTS;
    Object.keys(documents[0].Indexes).forEach(key => {
      this.cols.push({ field: key, header: key.toUpperCase() });
    })
    Object.keys(documents[0].SystemFields).forEach(key => {
      this.cols.push({ field: key, header: key.toUpperCase() });
    })
    this.documents = this.response.DOCUMENTS;
    this.documents.forEach(document => {
      // document.Indexes.merge(document.SystemFields)
      let indexes = Object.assign({}, document.Indexes, document.SystemFields)
      document.Indexes = indexes;
    })
    this._selectedColumns = this.cols;
  }

  @Input() get selectedColumns(): any[] {
    return this._selectedColumns;
  }

  set selectedColumns(val: any[]) {
    //restore original order
    this._selectedColumns = this.cols.filter(col => val.includes(col));
  }
}
```

Each time i set my cols to empty array, because if i send again data, the cols are added to existing cols.

This method is :

1. pushing indexes keys in cols
2. pushing system fields in cols

I do retrieve all columns as expected.
Next step consists on merging to objects in one object.

Now I tried to render the data :

```
<p-table [value]="documents"
         [paginator]="true"
         [rows]="5"
         [columns]="selectedColumns"
         [showCurrentPageReport]="true"
         [responsive]="true"
         [resizableColumns]="true"
         currentPageReportTemplate="Showing {first} to {last} of {totalRecords} entries" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[10,25,50]">

  <ng-template pTemplate="caption">
    <p-multiSelect [options]="cols" [(ngModel)]="selectedColumns" optionLabel="header"
                   selectedItemsLabel="{0} columns selected" [style]="{minWidth: '200px'}" placeholder="Choose Columns"></p-multiSelect>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="header">
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let col of cols" pSortableColumn="{{col.field}}">{{ col.header }}<p-sortIcon field="{{col.field}}">
      </p-sortIcon>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-document>
    <tr>
      <td *ngFor="let col of cols">
        <span> {{ document.Indexes[col.field] }}</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved one part of my issue concerning adding or removing columns.
I replaced :
`*ngFor="let col of cols"` with `*ngFor="let col of selectedColumns"`

```
<p-table [value]="documents"
         [columns]="selectedColumns"
         [showCurrentPageReport]="true"
         [responsive]="true"
         [resizableColumns]="true"
         currentPageReportTemplate="Showing {first} to {last} of {totalRecords} entries"
         [rowsPerPageOptions]="[10,25,50]"
         #dt
         [paginator]="true"
         [rows]="10"
>

  <ng-template pTemplate="caption">
    <p-multiSelect [options]="cols"
                   [(ngModel)]="selectedColumns"
                   optionLabel="header"
                   (onChange)="onSelect()"
                   selectedItemsLabel="{0} columns selected" [style]="{minWidth: '200px'}" placeholder="Choose Columns"></p-multiSelect>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="header">
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let col of selectedColumns" pSortableColumn="{{col.field}}">{{ col.header }}<p-sortIcon field="{{col.field}}">
      </p-sortIcon>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-document>
    <tr>
      <td *ngFor="let col of selectedColumns">
        <span> {{ document.Indexes[col.field] }}</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
</p-table>
```